# Most efficient way to refer to multiple controls. IE: the multi-WITH

Tags: vb.net, forms, basic, shortcut

I have had a little look around and cannot seem to find an easy way to refer to multiple controls in stuff like an IF statement, or to set a property to multiple controls etc. (IF exists = true!)

The 'shortcut'if you like; would best be described in illegal code such as:

```
Public Sub BreakCompiler()

  if string.IsNullOrEmpty(Textbox1.text, textbox2.text, textbox3.text) Then .....


  'As opposed to 
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(PartNumTextBox.Text) Or _
    String.IsNullOrEmpty(PartNameTextBox.Text) Or _
    String.IsNullOrEmpty(PartGRNTextBox.Text) Or_
    String.IsNullOrEmpty(SerialNumTextBox.Text) Then
        'Warn user
    Else
        'do nofin.
    End If
```

Or even more outlandish:

```
WITH Textbox1.text, textbox2.text, textbox3.text
    .ReadOnly = true
END WITH
End sub
```

The idea is to prevent having to run 3 if statements, or whatever, that basicaly do the same thing to 3 different objects...etc.. etc. Similar to a handler for multiple events that can be separated by a ','.

Im aware of looping through controls (IE for each control in groupbox.controls for eg) but that wouldn't quite achieve what I'm after here. (Say you wanted to skip a couple?)

Just thought id check the collective wisdom.

Comment: If you don't want to have OR or multiple lines (why not?) then your only option is to put them in a list and loop that list. You could have multiple list and loop the one that is needed. Or put something in the .Tag property of your control and update the ones with a specific value in the Tag for specific jobs.

Comment: @the_lotus Using the `Tag` property is a good idea; good point.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't anything similar to a handler for control properties in if statements.

You either have to do them separately (or add them all into an array), or, as you mentioned, go through a subset within another control.

However, one thing you can do (say you only wanted to change a certain type of control), is this:

```
For Each tb As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
    'do stuff here
Next
```

Another option is to create a `Sub` that will make the changes for you, and then pass each into the Sub.

```
Private Sub changeTextBox(tBox as TextBox)
    'make changes here
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah i use that quite often for stuff like locking all the inputs on a record form etc, but for doing something like just checking the numeric ones are what the should be. Thanks.

Comment: However, this coupled with If .Tag = "TheseOnes" as suggested by @the_lotus  above might be a simple efficient solution.......

Comment: @Josh The `.Tag` is a good idea for sure, if it isn't as simple as being separated by type.

Answer (score 1):

You want to process a variable length collection of some type of object.  One way to do this is to write helper methods that have an argument decorated with [`ParamArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ct363x9h.aspx) keyword.

```
Public Shared Function AnyIsNullOrEmpty(ParamArray controls As Control()) As Boolean
    Dim ret As Boolean 
    For i As Int32 = 0 to controls.GetUpperBound(0)
        ret = String.IsNullOrEmpty(controls(i).Text)
        If ret then Exit for
    Next
    Return ret
End Function

Public Shared Sub SetTBReadOnlyProperty(value As Boolean,ParamArray textboxes As TextBox())
    For i As Int32 = 0 to textboxes.GetUpperBound(0)
        textboxes(i).ReadOnly=value
    Next    
End Sub
```

Possible usage:

```
Private Sub DemoUsage
    If AnyIsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1,TextBox3,TextBox4) then
        ' at least one is empty
    Else
        ' all have value
    End If

    SetTBReadOnlyProperty(True,TextBox1,TextBox3,TextBox4)
End Sub
```

Comment: I had never used ParamArray, :) Where has it been all my life? (I seem to use that saying here alot.:)

Answer (score 1):

The newer versions of .NET allow you to use the `.ForEach` Linq extension on a `List` object. If you build a e.g. a `List(Of TextBox)` you can use `.ForEach` with an anonymous method to quickly iterate the controls in the `List` and manipulate properties and so forth. It's still a loop - but in a much more compact form. You can be selective about which controls are in a `List`, and have multiple `List`s etc.

Here's an example:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private _BoxList As New List(Of TextBox)
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        _BoxList.ForEach(Sub(tb As TextBox) tb.Enabled = Not (tb.Text = String.Empty))
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        _BoxList.Add(Me.TextBox1)
        _BoxList.Add(Me.TextBox2)
        _BoxList.Add(Me.TextBox3)
    End Sub
End Class
```

That's just 3 `TextBox`s and a `Button` on a vanilla form:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the particular example I was working on when I thought "There must be a better way" Something like this works perfectly.

It might be easier if trying to do multiple non type specific operations on different things. (Thanks @Sastreen and @the_lotus)

```
 Private Sub Validate_PartDetails() Handles PartNumTextBox.TextChanged, PartNameTextBox.TextChanged, PartGRNTextBox.TextChanged, SerialNumTextBox.TextChanged

    For Each tb As TextBox In BasicDetailsCustomGroupBox.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
        If tb.Tag = "notnull" Then
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text) Then
                tb.BackColor = Color.MistyRose                    
            Else
                tb.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor                   
            End If
        End If
        If tb.Tag = "notnumeric" Then
            If not(isnumeric(tb.Text)) Then
                tb.BackColor = Color.MistyRose                    
            Else
                tb.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor                   
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: controls.oftype could be removed and just do an entire form etc.